# mysql query left join and filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, where-clause

```
SELECT
 TABLE_1.ID,
 IF(TABLE_2.show IS NULL,0,1) AS RESULT,
FROM
 TABLE_1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 ON 
 TABLE_1.ID=TABLE_2.ID AND DATE(DATE_ADD( TABLE_2.DATE, INTERVAL +10 DAY)) < NOW()
WHERE
 TABLE_1.ID='1';
```

my question : table_1.ID=table_2.ID

```
TABLE_2.DATE = 06-11-2015
NOW          = 07-11-2015

if TABLE_2.DATE < NOW() = true  (RESULT = 1)

TABLE_2.DATE = 06-11-2015
NOW          = 05-11-2015
if TABLE_2.DATE < NOW() = false (RESULT = 0)

but
have TABLE_1.ID
have TABLE_2.ID
```

> i need
>
> 1.position "date ok", "table connection ok" = item old
>
> 2.position "date off", "table connection ok" = item hidden
>
> 3.position "date ok", "tablo connection no" = item new

but not working :(

Comment: *What* is your question?

Comment: You have an extra comma after `AS RESULT`.

Comment: Please edit the question. Show the input tables, the result you're trying to get from the query, and the result you're getting instead.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're saying in the comments. What does "kritel" mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 TABLE_1.ID,
 IF(TABLE_2.show IS NULL,0,1) AS RESULT,
FROM
 TABLE_1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 ON 
 TABLE_1.ID=TABLE_2.ID AND DATE(DATE_ADD( TABLE_2.DATE, INTERVAL +10 DAY)) < NOW() AND TABLE_2.DATE IS NOT NULL
WHERE
 TABLE_1.ID='1';
```

> 1.position "date ok", "table connection ok" = item old (it's work)
>
> 2.position "date off", "table connection ok" = item hidden (it's not work)
>
> 3.position "date ok", "tablo connection no" = item new (it's work)

my problems is 2. position